# How to create a line from the left side of the viewport to the end of an element inside a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create title that looks like this :

[image]

The horizontal line must come from the left side of the viewport and end at the same point the title ends. Ideally I would like to have everything inside a bootstrap column. So my markup looks like this for now :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="title-with-line">
                <h2>A great title</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to leave the HTML markup as it is. I can add more elements inside the column, no problem. It would be really good not to put anything outside of that column div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution that should work on any screen size. Thanks to the responses which led me to this solution :

```css
.title-with-line {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px; /* This margin only to offset the line form the top of the body for demonstration */
}

.title-with-line h2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.title-with-line h2:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 1px;

    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">

            <div class="title-with-line">
                <h2>A great title</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply border-top to the title and adjust padding for the same:

```css
.title-with-line {
  width: fit-content;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: calc(2em * 2);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="title-with-line">
                <h2>Nos prestations</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably would need to leverage a `calc` on the padding unless it's a fixed distance at all screen resolutions.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, Yes that makes sense. I'll update my answer

Comment: @deepakchethan Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't quite work the way I want it to. The title's text should always be aligned to the left of the column but in your snippet it doesn't, when applied to my project. I guess it's because de I'm using classic bootstrap containers (not fluid containers).

Answer (score -1):

```
//u have to use <hr> tag for horizontal line.

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is example</h1>
<hr>
<h2>This is example 2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An HR inside of a bootstrap column would be restricted to the width of that column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This code would do the job

```css
.title-with-line h2 {
  position:relative;
  padding-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.title-with-line h2:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:1px;
  background:black;
  right:0;
  top:10px;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="title-with-line">
                <h2>A Great Title</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```